# SSH connection fails on one interface but works on another - kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out

Tags: networking, ssh

For some reason I'm having problems connecting via SSH to my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS server through one of the two physical NICs in the machine with the following response:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out
banner exchange: Connection to 10.10.100.Y port 22: Connection timed out
```

I can connect to that same server on the other interface without a problem.

The ***working*** interface (`eno1`) is set up with the following IP address details so that it's temporarily available from my main internal network:

```
IP: 192.168.1.X
NM: 255.255.255.0
GW: 192.168.1.253
BC: 192.168.1.255
```

The interface that's not allowing me to connect (`enp2s0`) is set up for communicating on a separate network:

```
IP: 10.10.100.Y
NM: 255.255.255.192
GW: 10.10.100.253
BC: 10.10.100.255
```

I can `PING` the `10.10.100.Y` interface with no indication of basic connectivity issues. I'm coming from the same network as the `eno1` interface (`192.168.1.X`) and, as I said, I can SSH to that interface without a problem.

```
Pinging 10.10.100.Y with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.10.100.Y: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.10.100.Y: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.10.100.Y: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.10.100.Y: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 10.10.100.Y:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Just to throw another wrinkle into the mix, I also have an Ubuntu VM (20.04.6 LTS) running on an antsle Nano (basically a Rasperry Pi device) that's on the same network as the `enp2s0` interface described above to which I can SSH without error. Its IP address details for *that* interface are:

```
IP: 10.10.100.Z
NM: 255.255.255.192
GW: 10.10.100.253
BC: 10.10.100.255
```

I've looked at several questions and answers around SE and other sites and checked a whole host of possible causes, but still can't seem to get the SSH connection to work on the `enp2s0` interface. Here are just a few things I've looked at on the "problem" server:

### `/etc/hosts.allow`

```
sendmail: all
# /etc/hosts.allow: list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.
#                   See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: LOCAL @some_netgroup
#             ALL: .foobar.edu EXCEPT terminalserver.foobar.edu
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#

sshd: ALL: aclexec /usr/local/bin/sshfilter.sh %a
```

*This is using a GeoIP script (`sshfilter.sh`) to block incoming SSH connections from "dangerous" countries (both servers are using the same script).*

### `/etc/hosts.deny`

```
# /etc/hosts.deny: list of hosts that are _not_ allowed to access the system.
#                  See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: some.host.name, .some.domain
#             ALL EXCEPT in.fingerd: other.host.name, .other.domain
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#
# The PARANOID wildcard matches any host whose name does not match its
# address.
#
# You may wish to enable this to ensure any programs that don't
# validate looked up hostnames still leave understandable logs. In past
# versions of Debian this has been the default.
# ALL: PARANOID

sshd: ALL
```

*Using the `sshfilter.sh` script in the `hosts.allow` (supposedly) makes this work the way I'm expecting.*

### `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
Protocol 2
ListenAddress 192.168.1.X
ListenAddress 10.10.100.Y
LogLevel VERBOSE
LoginGraceTime 30
PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey
HostbasedAuthentication no
IgnoreRhosts yes
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog no
ClientAliveInterval 150
ClientAliveCountMax 0
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
AllowUsers myuser anotheruser
```

*I added the `ListenAddress` lines (and restarted the `sshd` service) but that didn't help.*

### `ufw status`

```
Status: inactive
```

### `/etc/netplan/netcfg.yaml`

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 10.10.100.Y/26
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 68.105.29.16
          - 68.105.28.16
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 9.9.9.9
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 10.10.100.253
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.10.100.253
        metric: 100
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.X/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 68.105.29.16
          - 68.105.28.16
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 9.9.9.9
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 192.168.1.253
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.1.253
        metric: 200
  renderer: NetworkManager
  version: 2
```

### `/etc/nftables.conf`

```
flush ruleset

# `inet` applies to both IPv4 and IPv6.
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0;

        # accept any localhost traffic
        iif lo accept

        # no ping floods:
        ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request limit rate over 10/second burst 4 packets drop
        ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type echo-request limit rate over 10/second burst 4 packets drop

        # accept traffic originated from us
        ct state established,related accept

        # accept ICMP & IGMP
        ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type { echo-request, destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, mld-listener-query, mld-listener-report, mld-listener-reduction, nd-router-sol>        ip protocol icmp icmp type { echo-request, destination-unreachable, router-solicitation, router-advertisement, time-exceeded, parameter-problem } accept
        ip protocol igmp accept

        # ssh
        tcp dport 22 accept

        # http, https
        tcp dport 80 accept
        tcp dport 443 accept

        # smtp, submission, smtps
        tcp dport 25 accept
        tcp dport 587 accept
        tcp dport 465 accept

        # pop3, pop3s
        tcp dport 110 accept
        tcp dport 995 accept

        # imap, imaps
        tcp dport 143 accept
        tcp dport 993 accept

        # count and drop any other traffic
        counter drop
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0;
        policy accept;
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0;
        policy drop;
    }
}
```

### `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.D.0.2           tcp dpt:5000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

### `route -n`

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.100.253   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.253   0.0.0.0         UG    200    0        0 eno1
172.D.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
10.10.100.192   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     101    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

### `netstat -tulpn | grep :22`

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.X:22        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 10.10.100.Y:22        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

### `ip r`

```
default via 10.10.100.253 dev enp2s0 proto static metric 100
default via 192.168.1.253 dev eno1 proto static metric 200
10.10.100.192/26 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.100.Y metric 101
172.D.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.D.0.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.X metric 100
```

### `ifconfig`

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.D.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.D.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:d3ff:fe5e:1111  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:d3:5e:46:11  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78  bytes 11868 (11.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.X  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::1a03:73ff:feb8:1111  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 18:03:73:b8:82:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 203434  bytes 14342810 (14.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6615  bytes 1573720 (1.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe1b00000-e1b20000

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.100.Y  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast 10.10.100.255
        inet6 fe80::6a05:caff:fec2:1111  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 68:05:ca:c2:b0:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 29985  bytes 11846128 (11.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18305  bytes 2268768 (2.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  memory 0xe10c0000-e10e0000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 891535  bytes 248668330 (248.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 891535  bytes 248668330 (248.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethb9d0ba4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::c76:3cff:fe82:1111  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0e:76:3c:82:f4:11  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
```

### `ssh-keyscan 10.10.100.Y`

```
read (10.10.100.Y): Connection timed out
read (10.10.100.Y): Connection timed out
read (10.10.100.Y): Connection timed out
read (10.10.100.Y): Connection timed out
read (10.10.100.Y): Connection timed out
```

### `ssh-keyscan 192.168.1.X`

```
# 192.168.1.X:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
192.168.1.X ssh-rsa <key here>
# 192.168.1.X:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
192.168.1.X ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 <key here>
# 192.168.1.X:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
192.168.1.X ssh-ed25519 <key here>
# 192.168.1.X:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
# 192.168.1.X:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
```

I've compared all of this information with the same information from the antsle VM to try and do as much of an "apples-to-apples" comparison as possible and try to find anything that looks obviously wrong, but nothing is jumping out at me. Where else should/could I look to find the problem here?

---

### TROUBLESHOOTING (from comments)

- I'm able to SSH to the `enp2s0` interface from the RasPi device that's on the same `10.10` network without a problem.
- I've removed the script from my `hosts.allow` and set it to `sshd : ALL`, but that didn't help.
- I've *not* yet tried disabling public key authentication and trying to log in with a password, but I'll see about testing that later.
- According to `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`, it looks like IP forwarding is enabled, although it doesn't appear to be running as a service (`Unit sysctl.service could not be found.`)
- I tried updating the `/etc/nftables.conf` FORWARD policy from `drop` to `allow`, but that didn't help.
- I've been looking through my network firewall appliance for anything "different" about the connection to that IP address (`10.10.100.Y`), but I keep coming up empty. The connection to the RasPi device on that same network is working just fine so the firewall knows how to route between the two subnets. If the firewall *is* the problem, it would seem that it has to be a rule explicitly defined for that IP address or something.

***Per Request***
Here is a "simplified" diagram of the network topology in play here:
[image: Network Topology]

- A Fortigate firewall is the "edge" device for our network.
- Interface 1 is the main LAN (`192.168`) and interface 3 is the "secondary" LAN (`10.10`).
- Interface 1 goes to a 24-port PoE switch that feeds the rest of our network here. Interface 3 goes to a small switch "dedicated" to the `10.10` network.

I mentioned earlier that I can access the "problem" interface from the public IP address, but only as long as I'm doing so from another network (*e.g., home*). Trying to SSH there from the `192.168` network here times out (*no message about `kex_exchange_identification`*).

Is this all tangled up in everyone's head now, or is it just me?

---

### UPDATE (still not working):

After digging around a while, I remembered that the 22.04 server (`10.10.100.Y`) has `nftables` running as the firewall (instead of `ufw`). I've posted the `nftables.conf` details above with the other firewall information.

Another interesting piece of this puzzle: My firewall has a "virtual IP" set up for routing traffic to the public IP address I've assigned on that server (`24.249.N.N`) to the internal private IP on the `enp2s0` interface (`10.10.100.Y`). I tried to SSH into the server from a remote network to the public IP address and it worked without a problem, so that seems to rule out a lot of the server configuration solutions and leads me to believe the issue may possibly be at the firewall level, even though I can PING that interface and even connect to another device on that same network without any problems.

Just to try and cover all my bases, I checked for the IP address of my client device in my `fail2ban` SSH jail, and it doesn't appear there.

Additionally, even though I don't have a clue how to actually read them, I ran some packet captures from end to end to see if anything stuck out. On the server, I ran `tcpdump -i enp2s0 port 22 and src 192.168.1.C` while I was trying to connect, which resulted in the following:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
11:28:04.935646 IP 192.168.1.C.50719 > 10.10.100.Y.ssh: Flags [S], seq 3110886807, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

1 packet captured
1 packet received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

It appears that only one packet made it to that interface for whatever reason. The other packet captures (from my client and from the firewall itself) add more information but, as I said, I'm not sure how to read it all, or even how to provide the detail here short of screenshots and/or uploading the `.pcap` files, so here are some pics:
[image: Wireshark capture during failed SSH negotiation]
*failed SSH negotiation resulting in the `Connection timed out` message*

[image: Wireshark capture to "working" server]
*this connection only failed because I didn't use my public key for the authentication*

Obviously there's a lot more active communication going on between my workstation and the "working" server.

I don't know if I'm more or less confused now, but I still don't really know where to look next.

---

### UPDATE #2:

I'm still unable to SSH to the `enp2s0` interface but, since I'm able to connect on the `eno1` interface, I've been splitting my time between working on that and trying to set up another package - [Remotely](https://github.com/immense/Remotely). The only reason I bring this up is because I've been unable to connect to that service *except* for a single brief "glimmer" of time where I was able to get the login/admin page to come up (*on the `eno1` interface, but still*). I don't know if one thing has anything to do with the other, but the fact that it randomly started working and then stopped again makes me think there's something very strange going on.

While I'm still open to the possibility that there's something in our network firewall appliance causing the issue, there are two things that make me think that that's *not* the issue:

1. I can connect to another device on that `10.10` network (the RasPi)
2. I can connect to the server from an outside connection via the public IP address I have assigned and routed to the `enp2s0` interface.

Of course, #2 also makes me think that the problem is less likely to be a configuration issue on the server, so I'm just totally confused.

Just to provide as much information as I can, I've also added my netplan configuration information. I had wondered if the problem was that the connection was "defaulting" to the `eno1` interface and that was causing some "confusion" in the routing, but I don't think the configuration supports that theory.

---

### UPDATE #3 (*sorta "fixed" (?)*):

Well, interesting development... Thankfully, I have console access to the machine, so I completely disabled the `eno1` network card completely and tried to SSH to the `10.10.100.Y` and it connected successfully. I even tried with the public IP `24.249.N.B` and it worked this time as well. I re-enabled the `eno1` interface and tried again and it was back to getting the `kex_exchange_identification` error.

Thinking that, perhaps the issue has something to do with the two different subnets "freaking out" the network on the machine, I went ahead and reconfigured the `eno1` interface to use another IP from the same subnet range (`10.10.100.E`) and I was able to SSH to `10.10.100.Y` successfully again. After editing the `sshd_config` to change the `ListenAddress` to include the new IP, I was even able to SSH to `10.10.100.E`.

So, it looks like something was causing some sort of conflict between the two interfaces (`eno1` and `enp2s0`) when using the two different subnets. Perhaps the firewall was "freaking out" when trying to route the traffic between the two networks. I'm still stumped by this and would really like to understand *why* that's such a problem, but it looks like all of the connections to that server are working as expected for the moment.

Comment: I've encountered that error when the hosts file are not configured properly, and since you have a custom script in there, I would start by removing that custom script and see if it works with the default config in hosts.allow and hosts.deny.

Comment: A few questions that come to mind...Could this be a firewall/routing issue on a different device instead of on this host? Have you tried SSHing from the Raspberry Pi to this host? Have you tried ignoring ssh-key authentication and logging in with password authentication, such as noted [here](https://serverfault.com/a/130351/1018673)?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. @rtaft - I've tried removing the script and just setting the `hosts.allow` to `sshd : ALL` and tried again, but it didn't change. I'm relatively new to the Linux environment, so I'm not 100% sure, but am I right in assuming that the `hosts.allow` takes precedence over the `hosts.deny`?

Comment: @mpboden - I have tried to SSH from the RasPi to this host (on the `enp2s0` interface), and it works without a problem. I've not yet tested without the key auth. I am open to the possibility that the problem may be in the firewall appliance, but I've gone through comparing all the rules and configurations I can find that refer to both the RasPi and this device and I'm not able to find any differences other than the actual IP addresses and display names. All of the same ports/services appear to be enabled, and I can't find anything else that looks like it's interfering with the communication.

Comment: So if you can SSH from the Raspberry Pi, then it’s not an SSH configuration problem. It looks like the Raspberry Pi is in same subnet, yet your problem is trying to access from a different subnet. So it’s either a routing issue in another device or you don’t have IP forwarding enabled. See [here](https://fedingo.com/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-ubuntu/) for details.

Comment: @mpboden Thank you again. According to `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`, it does appear to be enabled (`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`). Although, when I try to check the status of the `sysctl` service, it says that `Unit sysctl.service could not be found.`, so I'm not 100% certain about that at this point. I'm still trying to dig through everything in my network's firewall, but I've yet to find anything that would prevent the connection at that level.

Comment: I just noticed your `/etc/nftables.conf` file has a forward policy of drop. This could be the problem.

Comment: I changed that policy to `allow` instead of `drop` and restarted the `nftables` service, but the issue persists. I'm going to keep looking into my firewall appliance for other possibilities but, until I figure out whether the problem arises from there or something in the Ubuntu configuration, I'm going to leave this question open.

Comment: My biggest confusion about the firewall being the source of the issue, though, is that the RasPi is *only* available on that `10.10` network and I can connect to it just fine. The firewall clearly knows how to pass at least *some* of the traffic through to that network, so it seems to me that, if the firewall *is* the problem, it would have to be a very specific rule for that IP address exclusively.

Comment: Would you be willing to add a network diagram drawing of your physical setup? On a side note, in your Netplan config, you have 6 DNS servers listed. You can only have 3. Any after that are ignored. Also, you indicate this is a server installation and not desktop. Shouldn’t that imply the renderer is networkd and not NetworkManager?

Comment: **1)** I can sketch something together to display the physical topography of the network and post it in a bit. **2)** I wasn't aware that netplan would actively ignore anything beyond 3, so I just added all the ones I thought might be useful. **3)** Yes, it *is* a server, but I've gone ahead and - against "best practices" - installed a desktop environment on it since I'm still *really* new to the *nix world and I'm trying to teach myself how to do things by working in both environments.

Comment: It definitely sounds firewall/security related as it can initiate the connection and then loses it.  There is also the possibility of an external firewall doing this depending on your network setup.  For the hosts file, I would remove everything from both just to test it.

Comment: @rtaft - Yeah, I'm certainly open to that possibility, but I can't find ***anything*** in the firewall config/rules that seems to "negate" the successful/allowed connection to the other device on that `10.10` network. I'm still digging, but it's really starting to annoy the crap out of me.

Comment: @mpboden - I've added a "simplified" network topology diagram. I hope it's useful, but I'm really wondering if I'm just spinning my wheels here.

Comment: Are you trying to SSH to 10.10.100.Y from 192.168.1.C (host in upper right corner)? Is that network diagram accurate? I ask because I don't see how 192.168.1.X on interface `eno1` is connected to the 192.168.1.0/24 network when you state the small 5-port switch is "dedicated" to the 10.10.100.0/24 network. If that's true, then this host appears isolated. Also, if you're mixing subnets on the same switch, then the switch needs to be managed. Is this the case? Finally, why do you have two interfaces with two subnets on server? Can you simplify and use the edge device to route between networks?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to access both of the devices on the `10.10` network from the `192.168.1.C` host. I can SSH to `10.10.100.Z`, but not `10.10.100.Y`. The edge device (Fortigate) is what's providing the route between the two networks. The switch (UniFi) is a managed switch that handles traffic for a few different subnets. The reason there are two different subnets on that server is that I was actually intending to fully isolate it after I get the server set up and ready to "go live". This was supposed to just be a temporary thing until then.